# Adding a model attribute to the html template without encoding

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, html-encode, modelattribute

I am using spring boot(ver. 1.1.1.RELEASE) and trying to add a string model attribute in a html template.

the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping({"/", ""})
public String template(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("coolStuff", coolStuff);
    return "panel/index";
}
```

the HTML template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="text">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    [[${coolStuff}]]
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

thymeleaf's th:inline in mode "text" worked very well for that before, but now it is adding HTML encoding (escaping characters) to the provided string.
th:inline in mode "javascript" escapes double quotes so that is not working eihter.
Is there any way to put a string from a model attribute without encoding in the html template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `th:utext` to disable Thymeleaf's escaping but I'm not aware of a way to use that in combination with `th:inline`. I think you can still achieve what you want, but you'd have to change the value of `coolStuff` to contain the entirety of the `<script>` block.

Comment: in the end i did use th:utext like so, coolStuff is a javascript script: <script th:utext="#{coolStuff}"></script>   

... but this is using the "messageSource" bean for getting the value.

What I was trying is to inject the value direct through a model attribute. th:inline does read model attributes, but it escapes characters like: " < >.

I thought if someone knows something like th:uinline (unchecked-inline) where it would do exactly like inline but without escaping anything.